# Logic behind nested loops

Tags: java, logic, nested-loops

I'm having a hard time trying to understand logic behind a nested loops program that produce the output like this:

```
Pattern C
                   1 
                 1 2 
               1 2 3 
             1 2 3 4 
           1 2 3 4 5 
         1 2 3 4 5 6 
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

And here's the code:

```
void patternC(){
    System.out.println("\nPattern C");
    for(int m = 1; m <= a; m++){    //<-- a is for the desired number of lines

        //spasi
        for(int n = m; n <= a-m+a  ; n++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for(int o = 1; o <= m ; o++){
            System.out.print(o + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I know the first `for` is for the line, and the third `for` is for the digit that printed in each line. But I still don't get the logic in the second `for` (I know it's for spacing) but can you please explain me with example? Thank you.

Comment: to understand try printing out the values of `m` `n` and `o` instead

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand the basics of nested loops is to execute the code on paper. Just follow every step and keep track of every variable and you should have the same output on paper, plus an understanding of what the loop does.

Comment: Or execute the code in debugger and watch the counters and limits.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion for you if you are using an IDE:: run your method in debug mode to understand the flow. Here is a link on how to run a program in debug mode using Eclipse IDE.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Google for tutorials if you are using some other IDE. Else go with @Titulum's solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
void patter(){

  for(int m = 1; m <= a; m++) // a is desired no to be selected by user. 
  {           
    for(int n = 1; n <= a-m  ; n++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for(int o = 1; o <= m ; o++){
        System.out.print(o);
    }

    System.out.println();
  }
}
```